# Validate @Query in nestjs

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, backend, class-validator

I'm having some trouble creating this endpoint

```
@Get('/getByPatientDID')
  async getByPatientDID(
    @Query('did') did: string,
  ): Promise<PatientEntity | null> {...
```

the problem is, when i send throw postman another param like "email", did passed as `undefined` and accept. I don't want it. I have class-validator, ValidationPipe with this configuration. Also, don't let them pass because i'm sending another param that it should not accept. I don't want the application to allow me to pass a parameter other than did and not undefined.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      validationError: { target: true },
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
```

i tried usind this

```
@Query('did', ValidationPie) did: string,
@Query('did') @IsString did: string,
```

both didn't work. Also the application didn't let me the overload.

Comment: with `ValidationPie` you will validate objects. Thus, you need some class to represent that query object being validated. Try it out. `@Query() { did }: QueryDto` + global `ValidationPipe`  should work

Comment: So the only way is creating a dto? i can't use query params and validate if is the correct one or there's more than i need?

Comment: I mean, you could do `@Query('did', CustomPipeToValidateDid)` and ignore anything else, but if you want to restrict it so nothing else can be sent you'll need to at the very least validate against the entire `@Query()` object and not just one possible property of it.

Comment: I ended up solving it by creating a dto even if it is only one field.